# Как проверить валидность различных форм?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Пишу универсальный скрипт, который будет отправлять данные на сервак, только если форма валидна.
Необходимо как-то на стороне браузера проверять - валидна ли форма при клике на Submit. Проблема заключается в том, что *на разных сайтах, разная валидация*, а хочется найти униврсальное решение. Есть какие-то адекватные методы проверки валидации?

В голову приходит только использование

> $.ajaxPrefilter

для переопределения метода. Но это опять-таки не универсальное решение, быть может метод будет переопределён в дальнейшем для других нужд и использовать его не целесообразно. Кто что думает?

Comment: Надеюсь вы, не собираетесь валидировать минуя сервер?

Answer (score 1):

у каждого `input`а есть свойство `pattern` в которое пишется регулярное выражение 
по которому поле буде проходить валидацию

при нажатии на кнопку можно вызывать метод `CheckValidity ()`
которы в случае правльности возвращает true

Comment: Я ищу универсальный, это не работает даже с Jquery validation, возвращает постоянно true собственно.